# Protractor - input is not clickable despite using ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, protractor, cucumber

I'm trying to test an Ionic app using Protractor, and I have the following code in my page object that attempts to click on a checkbox:

```
  async shareWithPerson(name): Promise<void> {
    var input = this.inputWithName(name)
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf($('.toast-message')), 5000);
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf($('ion-backdrop')), 5000);
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(input), 5000);
    return input.click();
  }

  inputWithName(name): ElementFinder {
    var xpath = `//ion-label/div/span[@class="text"][contains(text(),'${name}')]/ancestor::ion-item/ion-checkbox`
    return element(by.xpath(xpath));
  }
```

However, no matter how hard I try, I always get the error:

```
unknown error: Element <button ion-button="" ion-item="" class="button-full-width float-right">...</button> is not clickable at point (897, 369). Other element would receive the click: <ion-backdrop tabindex="-1" class="backdrop-no-tappable hydrated" style="opacity: 0; will-change: opacity; transition-duration: 200ms; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;"></ion-backdrop>
```

Despite the fact that I'm wating for the backdrop to be invisible and I'm waiting for the element to be clickable. I can get around this by using `browser.sleep(3000)`, but I'd rather not nail in arbitary sleeps to get around the problem. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could it be you have other `ion-backdrop` elements on the page? Also, is it just becoming invisible or completely removed from the DOM? (thinking of applying other expected conditions)

Comment: Also, could it be a side effect of the fading animation somehow?

Comment: Ah, it's more than likely removed from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Try to chain the `perform` method to click.

```
input.click().perform();
```

Comment: That gives me a compilation error: `Property 'perform' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'. [2339]`

Comment: Yeah, `perform()` would not work here as this is not an action chain.

Answer (score 0):

As the presence of the element in the DOM is a more strict check by nature, I would try checking that instead of the visibility of the element:

```
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf($('ion-backdrop')), 5000);
```

Reference: [`stalenessOf`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf).

This is still a shot in the dark as I remember the need to put all of these "little" `browser.sleep()` calls here and there to tackle timing issues like that.

Comment: Same error unfortunately: `unknown error: Element <ion-checkbox ng-reflect-model="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ion-untouched ion-pristine ion-valid in-item interactive hydrated">...</ion-checkbox> is not clickable at point (101, 162). Other element would receive the click: <ion-backdrop tabindex="-1" class="backdrop-no-tappable hydrated" style="opacity: 0; will-change: opacity; transition-duration: 200ms; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;"></ion-backdrop>`

Comment: @Pezholio okay, two things: is it possible to turn the animations off completely during testing? Also, are there any other `ion-backdrop` elements on the page?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because element in on the web page but protractor is not able to see the element. Try scrolling to particularly to the element then perform click action.

Example:
browser.executeScript(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();arguments[0].click;”, inputElement);